# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Hi there i have a PayPal integration to do in Angular 5. I render Paypal buttons with this function

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.addScript) {
      this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
        this.abbonamenti.forEach((item, index) => {
          paypal.Button.render(this.payPalConfig +index, '#paypal-checkout-btn' + index);
          this.paypalLoad = false;
        })
        })
      }
  }
```

this need to load a different PayPal config foreach button:

```
    payPalConfig = {
  env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
                sandbox:    'AfOCNI-QeZrhkX2lT5e4xY0S2KTfgoDarEXwk4mkK0ge4EoeW25VN5cg5ZlNRrdJrWUctHWBGGbP4d2V',
                production: 'AUiobQL_EOnmPB4ytmb5ZZHbLZT4hXk7UZgMzGwkd8HFIR6qZ5qJZM3JOb91O4y5frw4197ygPyfbor0'
            },
    commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {

              // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: 40, currency: 'EUR' }
                            }
                        ]

            }
                });
            },
    // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
  };
```

but some concatenation or index is not work as well. If i try to add + index in function name i got error in syntax. I'm unable to figure out. And i'm very frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply `+` operator on the object. See the below line

```
paypal.Button.render(this.payPalConfig +index, '#paypal-checkout-btn' + index);
```

Here `this.payPalConfig` in above line is an `object` which is causing this error.

#### Fix

You should remove `+` and `index`, just pass the direct object

```
 paypal.Button.render(this.payPalConfig, '#paypal-checkout-btn' + index);
```

### Edit

Config should be as

```
      payPalConfig = new PayPalConfig(PayPalIntegrationType.ClientSideREST, PayPalEnvironment.Sandbox, {
        commit: true,
        client: {
          sandbox: 'yourSandboxClientId',
        },
        button: {
          label: 'paypal',
        },
        onPaymentComplete: (data, actions) => {
          console.log('OnPaymentComplete');
        },
        onCancel: (data, actions) => {
          console.log('OnCancel');
        },
        onError: (err) => {
          console.log('OnError');
        },
        transactions: [{
          amount: {
            currency: 'USD',
            total: 9
          }
        }]
      });
```

Reference - https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-paypal

Comment: provided the fix in answer.

Comment: Got these errors with your fix: ERROR in src/app/main/content/pages/abbonamento/abbonamento.component.ts(22,10): error TS2687: All declarations of 'payPalConfig' must have identical modifiers.
src/app/main/content/pages/abbonamento/abbonamento.component.ts(43,3): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'payPalConfig'.

Comment: src/app/main/content/pages/abbonamento/abbonamento.component.ts(43,3): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'payPalConfig' must be of type 'PayPalConfig', but here has type '{ env: string; client: { sandbox: string; production: string; }; commit: boolean; payment: (data:...'.
src/app/main/content/pages/abbonamento/abbonamento.component.ts(43,3): error TS2687: All declarations of 'payPalConfig' must have identical modifiers.

Comment: Looks like `payPalConfig` structure is not matching with `PayPalConfig` class. Please refer the official document for the same.

Comment: I added the sample code and reference. It may help you out.